# Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: лингвистика

Лиц, окончивших имеющие государственную аккредитацию

Comment: @Альбертт, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно, даже если не рассматривать это как предложение.
Пример предложения с этими словами.

Приглашаем лиц, окончивших этот ВУЗ и имеющих государственную аккредитацию.

Comment: В интернете ссылаясь на ТК увидел предложение такое, что и ввело в заблуждение:

Испытательный срок не применим... К ним относятся:


- лица, окончившие имеющие госаккредитацию учреждения профессионального образования и впервые поступающие на работу по полученной специальности в течение одного года со дня окончания учебы;

Как в рамках правил объяснить, что не правильно? Спасибо!

Comment: Здесь нет ошибки, хотя по стилю это неудобно для прочтения. Речь идёт о лицах, которые окончили учреждения проф. образования (эти учреждения имеют гос. аккредитацию).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать предложение полностью, чтобы судить о его правильности, а Вы не указали прямое дополнение УЧРЕЖДЕНИЯ.

"Лиц, окончивших имеющие государственную аккредитацию учреждения профессионального образования,..." - правильно, но лучше бы согласованное определение (причастный оборот) поставить после определяемого слова, чтобы было понятно, к чему относится:

"Лиц, окончивших (что?) учреждения профессионального образования, (какие?) имеющие государственную аккредитацию, ..." - всё понятно.

Comment: В оригинальном тексте - перечисление в именительном падеже (приведено ранее в комментарии), поэтому простым переносом причастного оборота текст не улучшить. (... лица, окончившие учреждения профессионального образования, имеющие госаккредитацию, и...) Появляется неоднозначность: "имеющие аккредитацию" согласовано по падежу и с "окончившие"; письменный вариант спасает запятая, но в юридически значимом тексте это не очень надёжно (в таких случаях возникают разные толкования). Думаю, составители видели эту возможность и сознательно от неё отказались.

Comment: Здесь нет неоднозначности, потому что аккредитацию имеют только юридические лица - учреждения(профтехучилища, техникумы, лицеи), а лица, окончившие учреждение, аккредитации не имеют, их документ - диплом об окончании.

Comment: Аккредитация (включая государственную) может относиться не только к юридическим, но и к физическим лицам: 

http://www.gosuslugi.ru/pgu/service/10001759657_.html#!_description

"Учебное заведение" здесь упомянуто на предмет требований к образованию классифицируемых "лиц"; вторым требованием кто-нибудь из не разбирающихся в запятых (грамматическая конструкция висит всего на одной из них) может счесть "аккредитацию".

Comment: Автору нужно было"в рамках правил объяснить,что неправильно"в его предложении.Мы оба ответили,что ошибки в исходном тексте нет.Только Вы указали на неправильность предложения автора,а у него всё верно,там нет одинаковых падежей,просто он не привёл предложение полностью. А вот ваше неверно по смыслу:"Приглашаем лиц, окончивших этот ВУЗ и имеющих гос. аккредитацию"-получается,что выпускники имеют аккредитацию на преподавание в вузе, а речь идёт о выпускниках, которые окончили заведение, имеющее аккредитацию,потому что некоторым отказано в аккредитации,поэтому дипломы выпускников недействительны

Comment: (?) Из моей (составленной из имеющихся слов) фразы никак не следует "аккредитация в ВУЗе". Речь может идти о наборе персонала для неназванной задачи, причём требуется диплом об окончании конкретного ВУЗа плюс гос. аккредитация в неназванной же области. Это всё, что из неё следует - хотя в ней могла бы быть и фантастика, поскольку это просто пример связывания слов в возможных падежах (в ответ на предложенное в качестве фразы). 

После появления цитаты из источника я сразу попытался переставить оборот, но увидел, что так хуже и решил не упоминать о такой возможности.